# Xcode & SFML linking issues: "Undefined symbol: sf::Window::pollEvent(sf::Event&) . . . "

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, linker-errors, sfml

## Problem

Attempting to compile solution via Xcode, while receiving the following error:

### Build Info

[image: Xcode_Build_Log]

## Make

Albeit, `make` compiles just fine, on the same local system with the same `libraries` and `dependancies`:

### MakeFile

```bash
# VARIABLES
## Binary
BIN := Entity-Simulation
SFML_V := 2.6.0

## Compiler
CXX := g++
CXX_FLAGS := -std=c++11

SRC_DIRS := ./include

LD_FLAG := -L../Build/Products/Debug

SRCS := $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS) -name '*.hpp')

OBJS := $(patsubst %.hpp, %.o, $(SRCS))

INC_DIRS := $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS) -type d)

# CONDITIONALS
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
    CLEAN := del $(OBJ_DIR) *.o && del $(BIN)
    LIBS := -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-systems -lsfml-window
else
    CLEAN := rm -f $(OBJS) *.o && rm -f $(BIN)
    LIBS := -lsfml-graphics.${SFML_V} -lsfml-system.${SFML_V} -lsfml-window.${SFML_V}
endif

# COMMANDS
## All
all: $(BIN)

## Binary
$(BIN): $(OBJS) main.cpp
    touch $@
    $(CXX) $(LD_FLAG) $(CXX_FLAGS) main.cpp $(OBJS) -o $@ $(LIBS) -march=native -v

## Objects
%.o: %.hpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXX_FLAGS) $< -o $@

## Clean
clean:
    $(CLEAN)
```

## Xcode Settings

### Xcode (Preferences) :: `Link Binary with Libraries, Embed Libraries`

[image: Xcode_Preferences-Link_Binary_with_Libraries-Embed_Libraries]

### Xcode (Preferences) :: `Deployment Info, Frameworks and Libraries`

[image: Xcode_Preferences-Target-Deployment_Info-Frameworks_and_libraries]

## System Settings

### Terminal :: `Library > Frameworks`

[image: Terminal_Library-Frameworks]

### Terminal :: `usr > local > include`

[image: Terminal_usr-local-include]

### Terminal :: `usr > local > lib`

[image: Terminal_usr-local-lib]

### Terminal :: `usr > local > Cellar > sfml > 2.6.0 > lib`

[image: Terminal_usr-local-Cellar-sfml-2.6.0-lib]

## Goal

Compile program in Xcode without conflict.

## Resources

GitHub Project for further inspection; in necessary [project](https://github.com/Justin-Byrne/Entity-Simulation)

Comment: The thing I notice is that although the XCode project and makefile are using the similar libraries the order is different. No idea about XCode but it's true of some compilers that library order is significant.

Comment: @john I altered the order of libs under (Xcode) :: `Link Binary With Libraries` and `Embed Libraries` with the same order as the `Makefile` (graphics, system, and window) without success. Yeah, the order of the headers during compile, makes absolute sense. However, after troubleshooting, it appears to present the same result !?

Comment: Well it was only a guess. The strange thing is that you have only two unresolveds, so some symbols from the libraries are being picked up. When library order does matter its because unresolveds from one library are only searched for in subsequent libraries in the list. Also if you have two libraries that refer to each other then one of the libraries needs to be mentioned twice. This is a linker issue not a header file issue.